# CSS div height overflows the document body when content is added

Tags: css, scroll, height, scrollbar, overflow

I have a `#container` div that is set to `height:100%; width:100%;` of the document body.  Inside the `#container` is `div#box2` that is set to `height:100%; width:200px;`.  When I add lots of content to `div#box2` the `div` height overflows the document body and a scroll bar appears.

How can I make `div#box2` `100%` the height of the `#container` (and thus `100%` of document body) and not overflow with a document scrollbar when content is added?

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aDdTe/

Essentially, `div#box2` should get the scroll bar, not document body.

**update**

I've edited my fiddle to better represent my actual dev scenario.  The new fiddle is here: jsfiddle.net/Nszjv and is working as expected in safari however firefox does not render the scrollbar for some reason.... any ideas on this?

Comment: It's because of `display: table;` and `display: table-cell`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `overflow` property in your css.

```
#box1{
    display:table-cell;
}

#box2{
    overflow:scroll;
    display:block;
    height:500px;

    width:200px;    
}
```

Here is the code on jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/gDKKr/

Comment: I like this solution; however, I've added some more elements and style to the mix to better represent my dev scenario and for some reason FireFox screws up the environment (safari displays perfectly). http://jsfiddle.net/Nszjv/ can you help? Notice the scrollbar in #box2 is gone and does not work